# Find the minimum for $(4 - x)^2 + x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + (2 - x y z)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Well, this is a good subject, but not actually the issue I am trying to find a solution for.

Recently, trying to solve one problem I just came to a similar minimization issue. Below is the same issue in more common form:

Find a minimum for $(a - x)^2 + x^2 y^2 + x^2 z^2 + (b - x y z)^2$

where we can consider $|a| \ge |b| \ge 0$.

Now, more interesting: I am sure that the answer for the common problem is $b^2$ and for the particular subject problem the answer is 4.

In both cases y = z = 0, x = a for the common problem and x = 4 for the particular one.

Very interesting case when a = b because there are continuum values for x, y and z! (this is not a factorial, I am just excited)

Finally, the most interesting: why I came to this minimization issue. This is not my goal to find the minimum of the function above. My goal is to solve another problem, I just provided a simple case of it in a form of real analysis for 3D functions.

This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Let X be a variable $n \times n$ matrix of rank 1 and let D be a fixed diagonal $n \times n$ matrix. We need to find a minimum of:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (d_{ij} − x_{ij})^2 $$

As you can see, in the example above we have a form for rank 1 matrix

$$ X = \begin{pmatrix}
    x & xy\\
    xz & xyz\\
  \end{pmatrix} $$

And a form for diagonal matrix

$$ D = \begin{pmatrix}
    a & 0\\
    0 & b\\
  \end{pmatrix} $$

where we consider $|a| \ge |b| \ge 0$.

I have a strong feeling that:

1. The answer is the sum of squares of all diagonal elements except for the biggest in its absolute value.

(thanks to [Martund](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/609343/martund), my original question was wrong and I typed "product" instead of "sum of squares"!)

2. The rank 1 matrix should have all zeros except for 1 element equals that biggest number on the same position.

If there are multiple biggest numbers, there may be a non-countable set of solutions, but minimum value is still the same.

Another feeling I have: I miss some elegant solution for this problem in a form of matrix and no need to create $2 \times 2$ form with 3D function. However even "simple" form of 3D function driving me crazy.

The main problem that feeling in mathematics is not considered as a proof, so I am looking for some help here.

**Some edition to the first version of this post.**

I looked at my notes I made several month ago regarding the problem. I found that I was considering slightly different function for rank1 matrix:

$$ X = \begin{pmatrix}
    x & y\\
    xz & yz\\
  \end{pmatrix} $$

so the function was $(x - a)^2 + y^2 + z^2x^2 + (zy - b)^2$.

Another note: for some values of a and b even at $ a^2 > b^2 $ we can achieve minimum when all elements of rank 1 matrix are different from 0, i.e. $x \ne 0, y \ne 0, z \ne 0 $

I made some serious investigation that time, so I am confident with the last note.

Answer (score 1):

Let the variable rank-$1$ matrix be $uv^T$, for some variable $n×1$ vectors $u$ and $v$ and the diagonal matrix $D=diag(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$.

Required sum=trace$((D-X)^T(D-X))$

Now, apply properties of trace, that it distributes over sum, $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ & $tr(A)=tr(A^T)$.

$$\Longrightarrow tr((D-X)^T(D-X))$$
$$=tr(D^TD)-tr(X^TD)-tr(D^TX)+tr(X^TX)$$
$$=tr(D^TD)-2tr(D^TX)+tr(X^TX)$$
$$=tr(D^2)-2tr(DX)+tr(X^TX)$$

Here the first term is a constant, hence it is enough to consider the remaining part. Also,
$$tr(X^TX)-2tr(DX)=tr(vu^Tuv^T)-2tr(Duv^T)$$
$$=tr(u^Tuv^Tv)-2tr(v^TDu)$$
Now, observe that the terms inside $tr$ are real numbers. Hence, required sum to be minimised is $$u^Tuv^Tv-2v^TDu$$
$$=\sum u_i^2\sum v_i^2-2\sum u_id_iv_i$$
Partially differentiate this expression with respect to $u_i$ and equate to zero, and get,
$$u_i=\frac{v_id_i}{\sum v_i^2}$$
Putting this value of $u_i$ in the expression to be minimised, that becomes
$$-\frac{\sum v_i^2d_i^2}{\sum v_i^2}$$
$$=-\frac{v^TD^2v}{v^Tv}$$
It takes minimum value when its absolute value is maximum. That happens when $v$ is equal to the eigen vector corresponding to that eigenvalue of $D^2$ which is maximum in absolute value. Let the eigen value of $D$ which is maximum in absolute value be $d_k$. Then corresponding Eigenvector is $e_k$(i.e. $k^{th}$ canonical basis vector), which is the optimum value of vector $v$. Hence, putting the value of $u_i$ we get that optimum value of vector $u$ is $d_ke_k$. Hence, required optimum value is 
$$tr(D^2)-2tr(DX)+tr(X^TX)$$
$$=\sum d_i^2-2\sum d_iv_iu_i+\sum u_i^2\sum v_i^2$$
$$=\sum d_i^2 - d_k^2$$
Hence, your feeling $1$ was quite wrong. But second feeling is correct because
$$X=uv^T$$
Hence, all entries but the $kk^{th}$ entry of optimum $X$ is zero, $kk^{th}$ entry is $d_k$.

Comment: First of all, my respect, this is great. Second - sorry, not product, I meant sum of squares of all elements except for the biggest (you can see that from 2x2 example) - not quite ethical, but I have to edit the question. My second feeling was that the problem is solvable using linear algebra and without 2x2 investigations. Your solution is a great point for that. However I know the source of the problem and I expect more simple solution. I am not sure and I maybe wrong, but this is too hard in my opinion. I still need to get deeper into your solution for better understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: Tell me through comments if you don't get something, it is very easy.

Comment: Linear algebra is there even when you start working with matrices, you cannot expect a solution without involving linear algebra to a question involving matrices.

Comment: Yes I agree (and I believe it's easy). Last time I've seen something like $tr(X^TD)$ in 1993 (to say nothing about some eventual readings in recent two years) so just need to refresh my knowledge. And I'd say an example of 2x2 is also interesting minimization problem, although it could be useless for the initial problem solution.